# Are there methods or considerations for real-time Gelman-Rubin diagnosis while running multiple mcmc chains in parallel?

Tags: bayesian, python, sampling, convergence, metropolis-hastings

I have a **Metropolis-Hastings** algorithm in **Python** and I parallelized it with the **multiprocessing library**. However, at this moment I can only do **Gelman-Rubin diagnosis** when all generated parallel chains have ended (at a certain number of iterations set from the beginning).

I want to do the Gelman-Rubin diagnosis every 1000 iterations of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm and stop all processes (chains) in case a certain criteria is met in Gelman-Rubin.

- **Are there any considerations I should take?**
- On the other hand, **could you recommend me a convenient pythonic way to do it?**

Thank you.